# Add a second bookmark to the same yes no button

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created a yes no button that hides a bookmark, how can i add a second bookmark to the same yes no button. My Bookmarks name is TextToShow. i just want to add another bookmark to the same field.

```
Private Sub CheckBoxNo_Change()
Call ShowHideBookmark
End Sub

Sub ShowHideBookmark()
Dim Sterilisation As Range
Set Sterilisation = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToShow").Range
If CheckBoxNo.Value = True Then
With Sterilisation.Font
  .Hidden = True
End With
With ActiveWindow.View
  .ShowHiddenText = False
  .ShowAll = False
End With
Else
With Sterilisation.Font
  .Hidden = False
End With
With ActiveWindow.View
  .ShowHiddenText = True
  .ShowAll = True
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ShowHideBookmark()
    Dim Sterilisation As Range, Sterilisation2 As Range

    Set Sterilisation = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToShow").Range
    Set Sterilisation2 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToShow2").Range

    If CheckBoxNo.value = True Then
        Sterilisation.Font.Hidden = True
        Sterilisation2.Font.Hidden = True
        With ActiveWindow.View
          .ShowHiddenText = False
          .ShowAll = False
        End With
    Else
        Sterilisation.Font.Hidden = False
        Sterilisation2.Font.Hidden = False
        With ActiveWindow.View
          .ShowHiddenText = True
          .ShowAll = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (as per JK's approach) your second bookmarked range is named 'TextToShow2', try:

```
Private Sub CheckBoxNo_Change()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim bVal As Boolean: bVal = CheckBoxNo.Value
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToShow").Range.Font.Hidden = bVal
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("TextToShow2").Range.Font.Hidden = bVal
ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = Not bVal
ActiveWindow.View.ShowAll = Not bVal
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```